# Must parameter passing into dispatch function be Object which containt 'type' property in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parameters, parameter-passing

i am learning about **useReducer**  in Reactjs. In teaching video or documentation about useReducer Hook, parameter passed into ***dispatch*** function is always a regular JavaScript object *(which contain **type** property and other infor helping to set new state in **reducer** function)*.

I have a question that passing object as parameter to **dispatch** function in reactjs is the rule of Reactjs or it is a coding convention of reactjs dev communication. In addition, instead of passing object as parameter to dispatch function, can i pass whatever data's type as i want to dispatch function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Extracting State Logic into a Reducer](https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer) documentation:

> **An action object can have any shape.**

> By convention, it is common to give it a string `type` that describes what happened, and pass any additional information in other fields.

It's a convention, not restrictive nor mandatory.

Here are some best practices:

- [Flux Standard Action](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action)
- [Do Not Put Non-Serializable Values in State or Actions](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions)
- [Write Actions Using the Flux Standard Action Convention](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#write-actions-using-the-flux-standard-action-convention). Prefer using FSA-formatted actions for consistency.

See this test case: [double invokes reducer functions](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/2153a29661e5998604225f81d93c8a20a1934adf/packages/react/src/__tests__/ReactStrictMode-test.js#L485)

You will find `dispatch(1)`, this test case dispatches a primitive number.

Take a look at the source code, the `action` will be pass-through to the reducer function [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4337c1c00609ec8d7ae399c736e9d37bb159fac5/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L1749).

*React v16.14.0*

```
// ...
const currentState: S = (queue.lastRenderedState: any);
const eagerState = lastRenderedReducer(currentState, action);
// ...
```

Comment: instead of passing object to dispatch, could I passing array ?

Comment: @LeoPkm2-1 You can if you want